# Scala functional code for iteration with a value forwarded to next iteration

Tags: scala

How to make this code more functional, where a value from the current iteration is preserved into the next (variable `last`),

```
def f(i: Int): Int = ???

var last = -1

for (v <- xs) yield {
  val start = f(v)
  val end = f(start)

  val res = if (last == start - 2) "abc" else "xyz"

  last = end
  res
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `foldLeft` should work. You can pass the value that you will need in the next iteration and the result in a tuple

```
   val list = (1 to 10 by 2)                       
   //> list  : scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
   val last = -1
   list.foldLeft((last, List[String]())) {
     case (r, c) => println(s"Current - $c last - ${r._1}")
     (c, r._2 :+ if (...) "abc" else "xyz")
     // c will be the value that you need to pass to the next iteration
     // r._2 will contain the list which you would have got with your for comprehension 
   }
  //> Current - 1 last - -1
  //| Current - 3 last - 1
  //| Current - 5 last - 3
  //| Current - 7 last - 5
  //| Current - 9 last - 7
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! Folding looks the appropriate way to approach this :)

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this approach with `scanLeft` (inspired in @mohit approach using `foldLeft`), here on a pre-processed collection of pairs for `start` and `end`, namely for instance

```
val a = Array((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Then in what follows, assume `s` stands for `start` and `e` for `end`, and so

```
a.scanLeft((-1,-1,-1)) { case(acc, (s,e)) => (s,e,acc._2) }.drop(1)
```

which produces triplets with `start`, `end` and `last`,

```
Array((1,2,-1), (3,4,2), (5,6,4))
```

over which we can apply the `if-else` expression; altogether,

```
a.scanLeft((-1,-1,-1)) { case(acc, (s,e)) => (s,e,acc._2) }.
  drop(1).
  map(t => if (t._3 == t._1 - 2) "abc" else "xyz")
```